# How to show datas on a ListView when it has multiple child in Firebase database as shownin picture

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

[image: I am having a problem to fetch data from the Firebase database from following database structure, as I have to send List in the database, so it's generating 0, 1, 2.. index and then the value. So how could I fetch data from Firebase to a ListView for this DB structure]

So please look at the problem iam facing.

Comment: What u have tried till now ?

Comment: if it would have values under keys then I would be able to do it, but as under keys, it has 0 then values, I am not getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `SuccessfulOrders` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root, to get that data and add it into a list, please use the following code:

```
String phoneNo = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference phoneNoRef = rootRef.child("SuccessfulOrders").child(phoneNo);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ListView<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String productName = ds.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                list.add(productName);
                Log.d("TAG", productName);
            }

            //Do what you need to do with your list.
            Log.d("TAG", list.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
phoneNoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logat wil be:

```
1000 Website Visit
SOCIAL MEDIA PACK
//and so on
```